# Can an IF/AND + INDEX/MATCH formula pull values based off multiple criteria?

Tags: excel

Lets say I have a table in sheet 2:

my headers go

```
Program    | start year | Salary  | meets some expectations | meets all expectations
business   | 2017       | $50,000 | $0                      | $1,000
finance    | 2016       | $60,000 | $0                      | $2,000
treasury   | 2015       | $80,000 | $0                      | $5,000
```

In another sheet (sheet1), I have a roster where I need to pulls in salary data based on that table. So, if employee 1 in row 1 has a start year of 2015, it'll pull over her planned salary of $80,000. Employee 2 in row two started in 2017, so their planned salary will be $50,000.

how can I use an index/match to pull over the correct planned salary? I feel like this is a long-winded IF statement to trigger an index/match value, but I don't know where to start.

Second part to this, how can I implement an IF statement to pull over the incentive numbers?

example:

`employee 1` `business` `2015` `meets all expectations` would receive a $5,000 incentive.

This table I made has only one business segment, there are dozens, so I'm sure that would factor in. Can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried? Looks like [multiple criteria `Index/Match`](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/) would work.

Comment: @BruceWayne so there are so many different combinations that can display different salaries and incentive packages, will I have to write out every scenario in an array formula?

Comment: To get the salary from the year, isn't that just a simple `vlookup`? the second half of your question is just a two-way lookup and in that case `match` and `index` are the correct formulae

Comment: @Dan it would be, if there was only one Program. there are like twelve different programs that all price their salaries different by each year.

Comment: @nicklanta in cases like that, the easiest option is just to create a new column which concatenates Program and start year and vlookup on that. So if this new column is columns A of your sheet 2 (moving the rest over) then in A2 the formula for this new matcher column is `=B2&C2`. On sheet 1 you can do this same concatenation inline so if program and start year and in cols A and B on sheet 1 you end up with `=VLOOKUP(A2&B2,sheet2!A:D,4,0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need multiple criteria to simply pull through the salary.
Can you not just do this:

```
=INDEX($K$5:$K$7,MATCH($D4,$J$5:$J$7,0))
```

[image]

To get the incentive value based on start year AND performance, you can use an INDEX/MATCH/MATCH:

```
=INDEX($L$5:$M$7,MATCH($D4,$J$5:$J$7,0),MATCH($F4,$L$4:$M$4,0))
```

[image]

EDIT: To allow for different programs without an array formula:

```
=INDEX($L$5:$M$7,MATCH(1,INDEX(($C4=$I$5:$I$7)*($D4=$J$5:$J$7),0,1),0),MATCH($F4,$L$4:$M$4,0))
```

[image]

The trick here is in first MATCH formula, which checks both the Program and Start Year:

```
MATCH(1,INDEX(($C4=$I$5:$I$7)*($D4=$J$5:$J$7),0,1),0)
```

Comment: I should have differentiated the data, there will be multiple programs, not just one

Answer (score 1):

With the data you gave in your example, this formula can work (enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>):

```
=INDEX($A$2:$E$4,MATCH(B7&C7,$A$2:$A$4&$B$2:$B$4,0),MATCH(D7,$A$1:$E$1,0))
```

[image]